# Что нужно знать для написания сканера памяти? С++

Tags: c++, память, процесс

Для развития выбрал себе задачу, пока что еще сложную для меня. Хочу сделать себе инструмент для сканирования памяти процессов, через который также можно будет дебажить. Со знанием стандартной библиотеки С++ проблем нет, но я совершенно не знаю в какую сторону копать. Как правильно сканировать память и что для этого нужно? Буду признателен, если пнете в нужном направлении, что почитать, с чем ознакомиться. Если есть какая-то литература по этому направлению, то вообще было бы шикарно. Просто нужна какая-то отправная точка и направление, не знаю даже с чего начать

Comment: подозреваю, что надо копать в сторону WinAPI (если вы в Windows), `ReadProcessMemory` и т.д.

Comment: @Zhihar да, я уже думал об этом. Сейчас уже читаю документацию по WinAPI, но меня также интересуют сами способы сканирования памяти, алгоритмы и подходы. Поискав по интернету, я нашел некоторые крупицы информации о том, как антивирусы и дебаггеры сканируют память, но этого очень мало

Comment: Если немного порассуждать, то сканер памяти, который просто может залезть в память к процессу - штука не супер-сложная. Но в тот момент, когда Вы захотите дебажить - Вам придется придумать что то вроде дизасемблера. Это, мне кажется, будет посложнее.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19606159/5045688

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вы хотите сделать что то на подобии ChetEngine? Мне кажется для написания такого кода мало будет знания одного С++. Было бы неплохо ознакомится с тем, то как вообще работает память в компьютере. Для начала тебе необходимо понять как работает ОС. Немного покурить Assembler тоже не будет лишним

Comment: Нет, CE мне не нужен, я просто хочу сделать себе инструмент для дебага на низком уровне. Это поможет мне разобраться в устройстве памяти, да и в языке с WinAPI попрактикуюсь. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы посоветовали литературу или другие ресурсы по ознакомлению с работой памяти в компьютере